# Switch/select default directory as store folder

Tags: php, jquery, html

Since I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to store images to a directory I would like to know if there is a possibilty within PHP or other to first SELECT the destination or store folder before the file is dropped. Normally, there is a default path to the folder defined in PHP such as:

```
// upload.inc.php

<?php

include("../inc/config.inc.php");


$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = '../../gallery/samples';


if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];         

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

}

?>
```

Now, the store folder is predefined. What I have in mind is to first move the file into the dropzone field and then secondly select, either by Jquery, html or somehow, the folder to which the file is dropped off to. I don't want to change the path manually constantly on the upload script. How can I establish this? [JStree](https://www.jstree.com/) for instance looks pretty well to have it done, idk.

Comment: Create a hidden input field with the destination folder and pass it as post, then use it? Something like that idk.

Comment: Yes, but by doing this the action method on form would send it off to the PHP file (server side) in which the path is predefined. Basically the same, isn't it? I would rather click that destination folder and then initiate that procedure.

Comment: Having an input field allows you to dynamically change it using javascript.

Comment: Could you give me a example how it would look like with JS included so I can get an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a name stored in JavaScript that you want to use as the folder to store the uploads, you'll need to create a hidden HTML form element that gets populated with JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="storefolder" name="storefolder">
```

JS:

```
var storefolder = document.getElementById["storefolder"];
storefolder.value = [VARIABLE]; // Whatever changes the folder needs to pass through here
```

PHP:

```
$storeFolder = $_POST["storefolder"];
```

Now your JavaScript variable will become your PHP variable, without the user ever seeing it outputted in the form. Note that you could also make the input field *visible* (with `type=text`), and simply use its value to pass directly through to the PHP if need be, bypassing the need for any JavaScript.

Hope this helps!

Comment: alright, looks promising to me. I'm gonna try this. All I need now is something like JStree that shows the main and subfolders to select from. By checking any of them the attribute is assigned to the var as shown above. So far so good. I upvoted this.

Comment: @what_me -- I'm unfamiliar with how JSTree creates elements, but I assume that you can assign them to a variable fairly easily, or at the least target the DOM. As long as you can get the folder to assign to `storefolder.name`, there shouldn't be any problems :) Also, you actually marked this answer as the solution to the problem, rather than upvoting it. You can't actually 'vote up' until you have 15 reputation, which you'll earn very quickly -- you earned two reputation just for marking this answer as correct :)

Comment: You should set the value, not the name.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes -- Ahh yes. I was confused by the fact that PHP receives the `name` attribute to identify the `$_POST` from the form. You do in fact need to modify `.value` instead. Thanks for pointing this out :)